# #613 when creating customaudiences

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

Why do I get a error "#613 Calls to this api have exceeded the rate limit." when using `/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/customaudiences`? I'm able to create 22 customaudiences POST's pr 6 minuts.

That's far from good enough. Any ideas?

I've tried to use facebooksdk.nets SDK, and done some simple post's myself.

Also I've tried with a few users accessTokens. It's still the same. I seem to be throttled at the 22 customaudiences create POSTs each 6 minuts.

My app is still in the developer access level.

Thanks!

Comment: And as far as I'm aware, the docs states that the marketing API is exempt from throtteling. I'm really baffled here. How would one go around creating a working, functioning app with an allotment of about 200 (6/60*22) POST's?

Comment: Docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting

Comment: my expectation is that you are on the development tier of the marketing API which is heavily throttled. What are you doing that requires so many custom audiences?

Comment: Hi Paul. We have a large website, with specific target audiences. I'm trying all in all to create about 5.800 customaudiences. After my initial import of these, then I'll be using the marketing API to create ads. No more audiences :-)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the limits, but 5,800 sounds like a lot. I'm guessing that amount is not actually allowed. If you're creating audiences for specific products, you should instead look at dynamic product ads.

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for taking your time to help me along. We sell one of products. When its sold on our site. Then no more. I track visits to this product with the pixel and retargeting events equal to my custom audiences. When i get a new product in, which sortof fits an audience, then i want to retarget these visitors, with the new product. Facebook allows 10.000 ca's btw :-)

Comment: I think 10k depends on the type of account you have, some have far fewer. Using dynamic ads with the upsell capabilities may still be a better solution, which says "people who bought these kinds of products, show them these products" and can work out which product is the best one to show which person.